# std::map find_if condition style confusion

Tags: c++, stl

I'd like to use `std::find_if` to search for the first element in my map that has a certain value in a specific element of its value structure.  I'm a little confused though.  I think I need to use bind1st or bind2nd, but I'm not positive that's the right way to go.

Here's some pseudo-code:

```
struct ValueType { int x, int y, int z };

std::map<int, ValueType> myMap;

... {populate map}

std::map<int, ValueType>::iterator pos = std::find_if(myMap.begin(), myMap.end(), <?>);
```

So, let's say that I wanted to find the first element of the map where the .x member of the ValueType was equal to a certain integer value (which can change each call).

What would be the best way to write a function or function object to achieve this?  I understand that the <?> has to be a unary predicate which makes me think I'll need bind1st or bind2nd to provide the integer value I'm checking for, but I'm not sure how to go about it.  It's been way too long since I looked at this stuff!  >.<

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Elements in the map are not sorted by value, they are sorted according to the key. So the phrase "the first element" has not much sense.

To find *some* element (not the first) that has `x` equal to some value you can write the functor as follows:

```
struct check_x
{
  check_x( int x ) : x_(x) {}
  bool operator()( const std::pair<int, ValueType>& v ) const 
  { 
    return v.second.x == x_; 
  }
private:
  int x_;
};
```

Then use it as follows:

```
// find any element where x equal to 10
std::find_if( myMap.begin(), myMap.end(), check_x(10) );
```

Comment: Since elements in the map are sorted by key, the order of entries is well-defined, and asking for the first one fulfilling a condition is thus also well-defined.

Comment: Yes, it is well-defined. But the order is not dependent on the value of the ValueType. That's what I was trying to say.

Answer (score 31):

You can use a lambda function

```
int val = ...;
auto it = std::find_if(myMap.begin(), myMap.end(), 
   [val](const std::pair<int, ValueType> & t) -> bool { 
      return t.second.x == val;
   }
);
```

But as Kirill V. Lyadvinsky answer suggests the "first" element may not be what you expect.

Answer (score 8):

For the lazy, use a C++17 auto lambda, then you don't need to be verbose with the type.

```
const auto it = std::find_if(myMap.begin(), myMap.end(), [&val](const auto &it) { 
      return it.second.x == val; // Comparing with the object
   }
);
```

Answer (score 5):

Building on all the answers above I cheat by using decltype with C++11 semantics.

```
auto beg_ = myMap.begin();
auto end_ = myMap.end();
auto it = find_if(beg_, end_,
    [&some_val](decltype(*beg_) & vt) {
        return vt.second == some_val;});
if (end_ != it) {
    auto key_found = (*it).first;
} else {
    // throw error not found.
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
struct Pred
{
    Pred(int x) : x_(x) { }
    bool operator()(const std::pair<int, ValueType>& p)
    {
        return (x_ == p.second.x);
    }
private:
    int x_;
};

... = std::find_if(myMap.begin(), myMap.end(), Pred(NUMBER));
```

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't have anything to do with `std::bind1st` or `std::bind2nd`. First of all, you have to keep in mind that the elements of a map are key-value pairs, in your case `std::pair<int,ValueType>`. Then you just need a predicate that compares the x member of the second member of yuch a pair against a specific value:

```
struct XEquals : std::unary_function<std::pair<int,ValueType>,bool>
{
    XEquals(int _x)
        : x(_x) {}
    bool operator()(const std::pair<int,ValueType> &v) const
        { return p.second.x == x; }
    int x;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to search also in values then may be better to use [Boost Bimap](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/bimap/doc/html/index.html) in order not to be slow?

Answer (score 0):

using **Boost.Bind** and **Boost.Lambda**:

```
...
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/lambda/lambda.hpp>
...
typedef std::map<int, ValueType> MapType;
...
MapType::iterator pos = std::find_if(myMap.begin(), myMap.end(), 
    boost::bind(&ValueType::y, boost::bind(&MapType::iterator::value_type::second, _1)) == magic_number);
```