# How to search a map with multiple keys with one of its keys?

Tags: c++, dictionary

I have a class with a key containg two integers

```
class TKey {
  public:
    int iKey1;
    int iKey2;
};

class TData : public TKey {
  public:
    int iData;
};


typedef map<TKey, TData, less <TKey> >    MapData;
typedef MapData::iterator                 ItData;

TMapData mapData;

mapData.push_back(...);
mapData.push_back(...);
```

Now I would like to find the item with iKey1 == 10 for example!

I can't use

```
  TKey theKey;
  theKey.iKey1 = 10;
  theKey.iKey2 = void;   // <<<<<

  ItData it = mapData.find(theKey);
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Use `std::find_if`. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8054223/1231073)

Answer (score 0):

You can perform custom search using [`std::find_if`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/find_if/) function.

```
struct check_iKey1
{
  check_iKey1( int iKey1) : iKey1_(iKey1) {}
  bool operator()( const std::pair<int, int>& v ) const 
  { 
    return v.first == iKey1_; 
  }
private:
  int iKey1_;
};


ItData it = std::find_if( mapData.begin(), mapData.end(), check_iKey1(10) );
```

### Disclaimer:

Written in browser. Not compiled! Taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8054223/1231073).

Comment: thanks. Does find_if uses the optimized algorithms of the map itself e.g. binary sorted list or something in that direction?

Comment: @Holonout.. No. `std::find_if` uses linear search. To perform binary search, you can use [`std::lower_bound`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/lower_bound/).

Answer (score 0):

```
class TKey {
 public:
 int iKey1;
 int iKey2;

 TKey( int v1, int v2):iKey1(v1), iKey2(v2){}

 bool operator<( const TKey& r ) const
 {
   if( iKey1 < r.iKey1 )
      return true;
   return false;
 }      
};

/// class TData : public TKey { - wrong!
class TData{
 public:
 int iData;
 TData() {};
 TData( int v):iData(v){}   
};


typedef map<TKey, TData/*, less <TKey>*/ >    MapData; /// less by default
typedef MapData::iterator                 ItData;

int main()
{   
  MapData mapData;

  mapData[TKey( 5, 0 )] = TData( 9 );
  mapData[TKey( 3, 0 )] = TData( 2 );
  mapData[TKey( 10, 4 )] = TData( 6 );

  auto i = mapData.find( TKey( 10,5 ) );

  if( i != mapData.end() )
    cout << i->second.iData << endl;
  else
    cout << "not found" << endl;

 return 0;
}
```

Comment: clever! ^^ but I need the key within the class for writing to the database. This question lead me to my next one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35036734/how-to-define-a-good-data-structure